# Php - find multiple strings inside code (from cURL)

Tags: php, curl

I want to extract a "name" and an "ID" from a table which is loaded via a url. the table always contain different values. 
One table could be this one: https://www.lectio.dk/lectio/262/FindSkema.aspx?type=stamklasse
i want to take every name and the id in the link its pointing to.
ex: name: 1m/id: 4514546468 (id from link: https://www.lectio.dk/lectio/262/SkemaNy.aspx?type=stamklasse&klasseid=4514546468)

how do i filter everything away but the things i need ? i get the source code with cURL and want to filter away the code so i have what i need left.

i did this whit a list with always fixed values, but since the table is always with different values i cant use the same code:

```
    <?php

        $ch = curl_init("http://www.lectio.dk/lectio/login_list.aspx");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);

          $output = curl_exec($ch); // do it!

          curl_close($ch); // close handle
          $expld = explode("<a", $output);
          $list = array();
          $remove = array("/", "d");
          $removefrom = array("/", "'", ">", "<");
          foreach($expld as $key){
              $gymnr = substr($key, 15, 3);
              $gymnr = str_replace($remove, "", $gymnr);
              $gymname = substr($key, 54);
              $gymname = str_replace($removefrom, "", $gymname);
              $gymname = substr($gymname, 0, -40);
              $prelist = array($gymname, $gymnr);
              $gymlist[] = $prelist;
          };
          unset($gymlist[0]);

          foreach($gymlist as $school){

              echo "<li data-id='".$school[1]."'>".$school[0]."</li>";

          }
    ?>
```

I think i can use regex to filter this, but i don't know enough about it, i need examples or solutions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML/XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml)

Comment: Using regular expressions is *not* the best approach here. PHP (especially more recent versions) has excellent DOM parsing capabilities. See the question I marked as a 'duplicate' for more information.